# Errorless PHP Login Script not Working

Tags: php

I'm using the following:

Firefox 31.0 (Cookies disabled)
WAMP Server 2.

The problem is that, even if I'm using the correct login account, the browser would just redirect me back into to the login page.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
 {
    session_start();

    $username = isset($_POST['username']);
    $password = isset($_POST['password']);

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root',"") or die ("Connection Failed.");
    mysql_select_db('abel', $con) or die ("Database connection Error.");

    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            header ('Location: login.php');
            die();
        }


    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
        {
            //echo "GOOD";
            $_SESSION['SES_ID'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['SES_UNAME'] = $row['username'];
            header('location: home.php');
            die();
        }
        else 
        {
            //echo "BAD";
            header('location: login.php');
            die();
        }
    }
 ?>
```

The problem (I think) if not on the query is on the If Else. It skips the statements under IF and just jumps directly to the ELSE statement, which redirect me back to the login page, again.

The code has no errors, but maybe, logically wrong, or is it the browser. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check if the username / password inputted are correct? I think $username = isset($_POST['username']) might be wrong since isset returns a boolean value.

Comment: How are you going to use sessions if you have disabled cookies? And please don't say "pass the sessionid in the url"

Comment: Sidenote: If you're not using anything **but** a safe password storage (hashing) algo, then call this a *blessing in disguise*. It's just a matter of time before your site gets hacked. Not to mention the fact that you should be using (mysqli-PDO) prepared statements.

Comment: To help you out next time, some simple `echo` debugging would have helped you catch this yourself. For example, you could insert `echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";` to find out what query is really running. You could then even run that query directly to see what it's returning, etc. (That's just general advice to help with your troubleshooting mindset. Please do look into all of the security concerns being mentioned here.)

Comment: How do you expect sessions to work with cookies disabled?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Your particular code is thankfully NOT vulnerable, due to your other bugs, but if you fix them, then you will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);
```

This sets username and password to merely a boolean that indicates whether the posted values are there or not. Since you use these variables in the query, the query will fail (unless you have a user '1' with password '1').

A possible, but not very good, way to fix it would be:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

But then you are open to SQL Injection, since anyone could just post any character to break your query. What if a password contains a `;`, or worse: a partial SQL statement?
So even better is:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

mysql_real_escape_string will escape invalid characters, so they can be used quite safely in a query.
But then, still, you are using an outdated, deprecated set of functions to connect and work with MySQL. Therefor, please read the warning on the [MySQL introduction page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) (which is also repeated on just about every other page related to this library).

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
> for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead,
> either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the
> [MySQL API Overview](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

So far for MySQL. Next chapter is sending and storing passwords. You should do this preferably over HTTPS (maybe you do already, I hope so). And as a rule, you should never store passwords as plain text in a database. Actually you should not store them encrypted either. You should *hash* them. And even then, add some *salt*.
The exact details are to long to explain here, but there are good explanations for this. Here is a random one: [Serious Security: How to store your users' passwords safely](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/)

Comment: Maybe even tack on a dash of `stripslashes()` and/or `trim()`, should there be any *accidental* spaces entered. I'm just thinking outloud ;)

Comment: Maybe I would like my password to end with a space or even tab character. Would be nice if that was just possible. :)

Comment: Yes, it would be nice but would most likely cause havoc somewhere down the line. :)

Comment: If you implement it right, it wouldn't. You should start hashing it as soon as possible. If a user made a typo when setting/changing the password, it would probably by caught by a 'confirm this password' check, or otherwise they would probably be able to request a new password. If they made an error while logging in, they could just try again and likely not make the same error again. I don't think an accidental space isn't different from accidental other typos, especially since in a password field, you would actually *see* the space (as a dot).

Comment: Btw, that's a great link to the *"Serious Security: How to store your users' passwords safely"* page. It's the first time I see it. Definitely worthy of a bookmark, and then some.

Answer (score 3):

First problem:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);
```

`isset` returns a boolean. So further on in your script where you use `$username` it is either true/false and not the submitted data.

**Security concern:**
You are not escaping user submitted data when passing it to the SQL statement opening you up to SQL injection. If you insist on using `mysql` then I would suggest adding before your MySQL query:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the return value of isset function in the var replaces original value you posted through browser.

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
```

And I recommend you to use better approach to SQL handling like using PDO extension.